# Create Dynamic Razor HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I create dynamic Razor lines like:

```
@{
    string atr = "MyAttribute";
    string s = "@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type.Word." + atr + ")";
}
```

and make these lines to be rendered as Razor lines?

I tried:

```
@(new HtmlString(s))
```

and

```
@Html.Raw(s)
```

But no luck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my research, I found out this is not doable. Instead of creating dynamic razor lines, I created a new Helper class in Helpers directory I created and defined a function that returns the Word in wanted language:

```
public abstract class Helper<T> : WebViewPage<T> 
{
    int languageID = Convert.ToInt16(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"]);
    public virtual string getWord (int? id)
    {
        string wantedWord = //operations..;
        return wantedWord;
    }
}
```

And defined the pageBaseType in my WebConfig.xml in Views directory.

```
<pages pageBaseType="MyProject.Helpers.Helper">
```

And I call the function in my Views:

```
@getWord(//variables)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is achievable but not using HtmlHelpers, instead use directly created html like this:

```
@foreach(var modelItem in Model){
    string atr = "MyAttribute";
    string tag = string.Format(@"<a href=""{0}"">{1}</a>","#",modelItem.Type.Word+atr);
    <text>@tag</text>
}
```

Inside the razor brackets you can do conditional statements that will result in dynamic html

Comment: @{ string atr = "." + "MyAttribute";
  string tag = string.Format(@"<a href=""{0}"">{1}</a>","#", item.Type.Word + atr); }
<text>@tag</text>

Tried this but it returns, "{MyProjectName}.Models.Word.Tr"